# Find and add MToon shader (from addon) with a script

Tags: python, shaders

I'm trying to use python to reproduce this setup :

[image]

This shader called "MToon_unversioned" comes from this addon : https://vrm-addon-for-blender.info/en/

The problem is that the shader can't be accessed the same way a Principled BSDF would with :

```
def applyingTexture(obj):
  mat = bpy.data.materials.new(name="Base Material")
  mat.use_nodes = True
  bsdf = mat.node_tree.nodes["Principled BSDF"]
  obj.data.materials[0] = mat
```

I.e if I replace "Principled BSDF" with "MToon_unversioned" it doesn't work.

Does anyone know how I can find back this shader ?

A potential solution would be to use the command

```
bpy.ops.node.add_search(use_transform=True, settings=[{"name":"node_tree", "value":"bpy.data.node_groups['MToon_unversioned']"}], node_item='91')
```

But I got an error `RuntimeError: Operator bpy.ops.node.add_search.poll() failed, context is incorrect`

Thanks a LOT for your help !!

Comment: You need to check what the name of the node is in the shader editor. Presumably "MToon_unversioned" is just the label. You could also iterate over the nodes and check whether one has the `label` set to this string.

Answer (score 1):

I eventually made it work. MToon_unversioned is actually a shader group, but it can't be used directly with `bpy.data.node_groups['MToon_unversioned']`, which is actually a node_tree and not a node

Instead, I created a new Shader group, then assigned its `node_tree` component to it with :

```
shader = nodes.new("ShaderNodeGroup")
shader.node_tree = bpy.data.node_groups['MToon_unversioned']
```